# Server not accepting connecting to client

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple Socket program and I'm right now able to create a server socket, bind the server socket to a port and listen for incoming connections after which, when I try to start with the accepting of the connection, nothing gets printed out.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char buffer[1024] = {0};
char *mes = "peepeepoopoo";
struct sockaddr_in server;
int addr_size = sizeof(server);

//xxxxxxxx Creating the socket xxxxxxxx

int sockfd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int client_socket;
if(sockfd_server < 0){
printf("Socket not created\n");
return -1;
}
puts("Socket created\n");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(8070);

//xxxxxxxx Binding xxxxxxx

if(bind(sockfd_server,(struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
printf("failed to bind\n");
return -1;
}
puts("binding completed\n");

//xxxxxxxx Listening xxxxxxxx

if (listen(sockfd_server,3) < 0)
{
printf("Listening error\n");
}
puts("Listening\n");

// none of the statements prints, almost like its frozen.

int new_Socket = accept(sockfd_server, (struct sockaddr*)&server, (socklen_t*)&addr_size);
if(new_Socket < 0){
printf("could not accept socker\n");
return -1;
}
puts("accepted\n");
int val = read(new_Socket,buffer, 1024);
printf("%s\n",buffer);
send(new_Socket, mes, strlen(mes), 0);

return 0;
}
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Not accepting *what* connection? There is no evidence here that you've tried to connect to this server. *Ergo* it is *blocked* waiting for that to happen. This is working as designed. NB Please format this illegible mess properly.

Comment: I agree with @user207421 - I just tested the code and it accepts connections just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I'm really really new to this so I wasn't really understanding why i was not getting the intended o/p but realised how stupid i really am.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you think should have happened ...

Answer (score 1):

1. [accept](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)

> If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is not marked as nonblocking, accept() blocks the caller until a connection is present.

**Question**: Do you connect a client to your server?

2. `addr_size` is declared as `int`, yet passed as an argument while casting it to `socklen_t`. Can you guarantee that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(socklen_t)`?
3. You read into `buffer` but do not null-terminate it before passing it to `printf` with the format specifier `%s`.